# C# String to DateTime with this format 2018-05-26T00:00:00

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm trying to get a DateTime value with this format 2018-05-26T00:00:00 on Visual Studio 2017 (C#). However, I am not able to do so after trying several ways such as Parse and ParseExact.

Here is my sample input:

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(2018,5,26,0,0,0);
DateTime convert = DateTime.Parse(date.Date.ToString("s"));
Debug.WriteLine("Checking the converted value here " + convert);
```

Sample Output:

```
Checking the converted value here 5/26/2018 12:00:00 AM
```

However, the only time i am able to get the format i want(2018-05-26T00:00:00) is when it is in string type.

```
String s = date.ToString("s");
```

The issue now is that I want the format to be 2018-05-26T00:00:00 when the type is DateTime. Is it possible though? Help really needed here. Appreciate any help that I can get.

Comment: Why is this question being downvoted?

Comment: The short answer is no.

Comment: You can format the string anyway you want. You have to use the right formatters though. Look into DateTime formats

Comment: Sounds like an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What's wrong with `date.ToString("s")`?

Comment: `DateTime` doesn't have format. It contains only value (amount of ticks). When you displaying date in `WriteLine` it will call `.ToString()` in background. So if you need particular format you need use `data.ToString("s")` everywhere where you want display a date

Comment: I agree with @Warty -- this should not be a downvoted question. So, +1. I also agree with @Jasen: if your requirements are to have a date formatted for the front-end, a formatted `string` type should be just fine (you can parse it to a Javascript Date if you need to do date comparisons). If it is meant to be stored in a database, you can store it as a Date / DateTime type and format it however you need in the business logic (or front-end) on retrieval.

Comment: Downvotes are probably because OP is asking about adjusting/maintaining a format while data is of type DateTime.  This is not possible and illustrates a misunderstanding of the DateTime type. Question then needs to be adjusted to something along the lines of "how do I format a DateTime to format X?", by which time this question becomes a duplicate of many others on this site. Disclaimer: I neither voted the question up or down.  OP: Make sure you understand what @Fabio said, that's the key to understanding what is happening.

Comment: It's alright that this got downvoted just now guys. It is impossible to get a DateTime value to be in the format I wanted. So i shall mark this as resolved. Thanks for the quick discussion, appreciate them a lot.

Comment: @Fabian I think there just might be a language barrier or miscommunication here. DateTimes do not have a format when they are DateTimes. But you can call ToString() on a DateTime object and format it anyway you want. I commented earlier about DateTime format strings, [see the docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) for a list of all of them. You can build out whatever format you want when displaying a DateTime **as a string** like this: someDateTimeObject.ToString(“yyyy-MM-dd”) that would be “2018-04-26”

Answer (score -1):

You can use this to get the format you want (2018-05-26T00:00:00) :

```
date.GetDateTimeFormats()[114];
```

Also, There are a lot of formats which you can see them though GetDateTimeFormats method on DateTime datatype

Comment: I don't think OP is asking for this.